# build.gradle.kts not recognising object as variable

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-kts

I have a `build.gradle.kts` and I'd like to store all the versions there as :

```
plugins {
    `java-platform`
}

javaPlatform {
    allowDependencies()
}

dependencies {

    val version = object {
    val androidx = object {
        val appCompat = "1.4.1"
        val core = "1.7.0"
    }
    ....

    api("whatever:${version.androidx.appCompat}") <-- not working because can not find "version"

}
```

When trying to use this `version.` is not working, any idea why?

Comment: What is the exact error message gradle shows? It seems ok.

Comment: That can not find "androidx" looks like this "version" is not the one that I'm using in the `api` but already tried with another name and it doesn't work :/

Comment: Is this an error in IntelliJ/Android Studio, or when you run `./gradlew assemble` from the command line? If so, add the full error from the command line to your question.

Comment: Truth is your setup would 100% work - you are missing something else. It is also important to tell that your approach is bad, there are better approaches involving listing versions outside of *gradle.kts